# Perfectly secure cryptosystem as many keys as plaintexts

Tags: keys, perfect-secrecy

Is a cryptosystem perfectly secure if there are at least as many keys as there are plaintexts?

My guess is yes but I am not sure, new to cyptosystems

Comment: See One-time-Pad. Also, note that the keys must be generated uniformly random.

Comment: Hint: What about cryptosystems that don't make good (or any) use of their key?

Comment: Take the definition of a perfectly secure crypto-system and try to use counting arguments on the sizes of the sets of the possible keys and possible plaintexts